# Python - String list check

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm relatively new with Python, so I still struggle a bit with character manipulation.

I tried many variations of this piece of code:

```
print([for element in string if element[0] == '['])
```

"string" is a list of [tag] messages, which i splited considering '\n', so I'm trying to format it and merge separated elements of the same message. Right now I'm doing:

```
for count, element in enumerate(string):
        try:
            if element[0] != '[':
                string[count - 1] = string[count - 1] + ' ' + string[count]
                string.pop(count)
                count = count - 1
```

But it only works once per couple messages, so my goal is to check if all are properly merged.

My expected output is `True` if there is a "[" in the first character of the current element in the string list. So I can put it on a while loop:

```
while([for element in string if element[0] == '[']):
   # do something
```

Comment: What does `string` contain? Do you want to check all elements for presence of '[' ?

Comment: add the definition of `string` in the code

Comment: done, edited with the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a list with the comprehension list. Maybe this will work better for your case

```
def verify(s)
    for element in s:
        if element[0] == '[':
            return True
    return False

while(verify(s)):
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

A succinct way to do this is with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). You can also use the build-in [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) which helps the readability:

```
strings = ['hello', '[whoops]', 'test']
any(s.startswith('[') for s in strings)
# True

strings = ['hello', 'okay', 'test']
any(s.startswith('[') for s in strings)
# False
```

Comment: Hohoo, that is pretty useful too, it's exactly the way I was trying to do with the right changes. In my code example I could do "any(element[0] == '[' for element in strings)". Thank you for your contribution Mark, appreciate it. Really learnt something new today.